# MATLAB nonuniform distribution of output to dynamically sized inputs

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to get 3 variables from workspace to simulink. I used demux block as in the picture here:

[block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUfTY.png)

It is giving me a block warning:

```
Nonuniform distribution of output to dynamically sized inputs in block 'invModel0/driving cycle/Demux'
Component:Simulink | Category:Block warning
```

I set Number of outputs to 3 and did not change anything else. I simply connected the input and outputs using arrows.

I am a beginner so, I do not know what I did wrong. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I simply used the 'from workspace' block for each variable.

[block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEbop.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).